# Can't implement node-like async.race function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I want to implement `async.race` function

```
/*
 * Takes array of functions and returns a handler-function of result of the fastest btw arguments
 */
async.race([slower, faster])(function(err, winner) {
  console.log(winner); // I'm faster
});

function slower(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback.bind(null, null, "I'm slower"), 1000);
}

function faster(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback.bind(null, null, "I'm faster"), 10);
}
```

The problem here is that `async.race([slower, faster])` returns function which should be able to handle results. BUT it return the function at the moment we haven't got any result.

Here's my code. The question is how to be at the last line

```
var async = {
    race: function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), 
            finished = false,
            i, winner_err, winner_data;

        var callback = function(err, data) {
            if (finished) return;
            else finished = true;

            winner_err = err;
            winner_data = data;
        }

        for (i  = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            args[i](function(err, data) {
                if (finished) return;
                else finished = true;
            });
        }


        return function(fn) {
            if (finished) {
                fn(winner_err, winner_data);
            } else {
                //QUESTION: how to be here. I need return function with not ready `winner_data` and check in while/setInterval when the results will appear?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we should return handler-function immediately, while the result which must be handled with the handler-function may be retrieved later (asynchronously). So we should predict two usecases:

1. Handler-function is called before we retrieve the result (`faster` function result) to be handled
2. Handler-function is called after we retrieve the result (`faster` function result)

Finally I end with next implementation:

```
var async = {
    // @param array - array of a functions
    // @return returns a function which accept handler-function as 
    // an argument. The handler function will handle the result of the 
    // fastest btw {@param array} functions  
    race: function(arr) {
            // indicates if the first (fastest) function is completed. 
            // If yes - there is no sense to handle another functions results
        var finished = false, 
            //  Returned errors / data of the first (fastest) function
            winner_err, winner_data, 
            // callback which will handle the results of the fastest function
            cb, i;

        var retur_func = function(fn) {
            // For the case if `smth_like_promise` (see Usage section) will be called 
            // before `faster` will be completed
            cb = fn;    
            // For the  case if `faster` will be completed before 
            // `smth_like_promise` will be called
            if (retur_func.redefined) retur_func.redefined(fn);
        };

        // callback which handle the result of each separate function that participates in race
        var callback = function(err, data) {
            if (finished) return;

            finished = true;
            // Tricky situation: we have data to be handled, but haven't handler function
            if (!cb) {
                // We pass `return_func` to the client and can't redefine it. 
                // So we redefine it property, which will be called instead function in future 
                retur_func.redefined = function(fn) {
                    fn(err, data);
                }
            } else {
                cb(err, data);
            }

        }

        // Start race! Afterwards only the first function results should be
        // handled with `retur_func` function
        for (i  = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {              
            arr[i](callback);
        }

        return retur_func;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var slower = function(cb) {
    setTimeout(cb.bind(null, null, "I'm slower"), 1000);
}

var faster = function(cb) {
  setTimeout(cb.bind(null, null, "I'm faster"), 10);
}

var smth_like_promise = async.race([slower, faster]); 

// you may call `smth_like_promise` immediately or wait until passed functions (`faster` or `slower`) will be completed
smth_like_promise(function(err, winner) {
  alert(winner); // I'm faster
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the function, and then execute it later. you were also using `arguments` when you should have instead simply accepted an array.

```js
var async = {
    race: function(arr) {
        var finished = false,
            i, winner_err, winner_data, cb = console.log.bind(console);

        for (i  = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i](function(err, data) {
                if (finished) {return;}
                else {finished = true; cb(err, data);}
            });
        }


        return function(fn) {
            cb = fn;
        }
    }
}

async.race([slower, faster])(function(err, winner) {
  console.log(err, winner); // I'm faster
});

function slower(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback.bind(null, null, "I'm slower"), 1000);
}

function faster(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback.bind(null, null, "I'm faster"), 10);
}
```

Comment: This has one downside. The two functions you are testing MUST be asynchronous. If they're synchronous, the test won't yield useful results and the callback will not get called.

Comment: what will happen if I only call `async.race([slower, faster])`? I suppose `cb` will never be initialized, but it will be called as a callback of `faster` function

Comment: It would error. If that's a possibility you want to handle, you'll need to modify it to handle that. `cb && cb(err, data)` should do, unless you wanted to do more such as logging which one is faster if there is no cb.

Comment: sorry, but I need a universal function, something reusable. There is no sense to call `console.log` instead of user's function in that case

Comment: ... it will call the users function, if it exists, else it will call console.log

Comment: I really like your approach. But this question is about how to do that with JS in the right way (I'm not JS programmer yet). Sorry about that, I'll upvote your answer anyway

Comment: So you're asking for an opinion on what is best then without specifying what best means?

Comment: no, I just want to say that `console.log` isn't the most universal way. Suppose you want to write your custom library for promises. And if user won't call `then` on just created `new Promise(fn)` within a second - you do `console.log` instead of callback. I'm just sure there should be another way

Comment: What other way would there be than console.log in the event the user doesn't tell us what they want it to do? the only other viable option would be to just do nothing. I don't see what this has to do with the question asked.

Comment: 1) The first option I dislike is to try recheck if `cb` is initialized in some intervals (lets say 1,2,3 seconds). Then throw timeout exception. 2) The second option I think about is redefinition of returned function from race method. But that may be impossible in javascript, here I tried to understand why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732198/redefine-function-btw-it-initialization-and-invocation

Comment: YOu could redefine it like you are trying, if you instead returned an object that contained the function. You could then update that object as much as you like, as long as you don't replace it.

Comment: great idea! Unfortunatelly that's kind of interview task, and I can;t change API. But your comment lead me to working solution! I can add new attribute to returned function (redefined_function_attr) which will be called instead of function if it haven't been initialized yet. Not so complex as it sounds. Here an example https://jsfiddle.net/jvj5rc83/