# Redefine function between its initialization and invocation

Tags: javascript

Why does this alert `Initial` instead of `Redefined`:

```
var inner = function() { alert('Initial'); }
var outer = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
       inner = function() { alert('Redefined'); }
    }, 0);
    return inner;
}
var f = outer();
setTimeout(f, 1000);
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to do something else? Explain us pls.

Comment: you would think someone with that much reputation wouldn't be lazy enough to type out "by the way" and "please".... What exactly do you expect it to do?

Comment: `outer` returns the value of `inner`, not inner itself. Changing what `inner` contains doesn't overwrite the function that was already returned.

Comment: @KevinB got it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the timeout to zero doesn't *necessarily* mean that the callback will be run immediately. Control immediately proceeds to the next line, where you return `inner`. At this point in time it has not been redefined and `f` points to the old `inner`, which is why you are seeing "Initial".

Change your code to the following:

```
var inner = function() { console.log('Initial'); }
var outer = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
       inner = function() { console.log('Redefined'); }
    }, 0);
    return inner;
}
outer();
setTimeout(function() { 
    inner(); 
}, 1000);
```

Now you'll see "Redefined", because we call `outer` which will redefine `inner` at some point in the future. When we then call `inner()` within the timeout handler, it is pointing to the redefined version and so it will print "Redefined".

You might wonder why we couldn't just do this:

```
var inner = function() { console.log('Initial'); }
var outer = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
       inner = function() { console.log('Redefined'); }
    }, 0);
    return inner;
}
outer();
setTimeout(inner, 1000);
```

But you'll get "Initial" here as well for the same reason; when `setTimeout` is called `inner` is still pointing to the original version.

Comment: that's do work, but unfortunatelly return result of `outer` will be used elsewhere, and an obsolete `inner` function will be invoked

Comment: @V_B It most definitely will. How can you expect to return a value immediately from an asynchronous operation? You don't know when that operation will be completed.

Answer (score 0):

This because the value of `inner` is set after the all of other JS is executed. That function is sent to other stack and is removed from the `main` stack. Even if you set the timer to **0 ms**; the setTimeout function will be executed when all other JS executed. Here's how your program is executed:

1. Initializes `inner` and `outer`.
2. Executes `outer` and initializes `f` with the return value.

BUT how does `outer()` gets executed? Here's how:

1. Hits `setTimeout` Web API which has a function which should execute after 0 ms but it will be sent to **event loop** and will be executed later. The rest of the code will be executed.
2. Hits `return` statement. It will access the value of `inner`. Now, remember your setTimeout function isn't executed yet. So, the function will move upto the prototype chain and find `inner`. As `inner` was defined in `Global` context. That value will be returned.
3. Finally, the `outer()` returns a function to `f` which is executed by another `setTimeout`. The function in `setTimeout` will also be sent to **event loop**.

Now, **event loop** has 2 functions to be called! One of them will reset the value of inner and the other will alert "Initial" but, the value of `inner` will be changed instantly. The alert will be displayed after 1s as defined.

Comment: I know how the event-loop works. I just hoped that funcitons are called by reference or so

Comment: @V_B: Functions are *reference values* just as objects. They have an identity and you can pass them around, but assigning a value to a variable does only change that variable.

Comment: @Bergi Please, can you read my edits? Tell me if I am wrong at any point ;)

Comment: @RexOverflow: Only at minor points: the callback that `alert(…)`s is not yet executed when `inner` is set. You mean *scope* not prototype chain. And I've never heard the term "the other stack", there's an *event queue* and of course each *turn* of the event loop uses its own stack (dunno what you're referring to).